# react-virtualized IE11 performance

Tags: react-virtualized

I am new in React world. I am using react-virtualized Grid to show a lot of elements.
At once I am showing 5x8 elements on page + 5x8 overscanRowCount.
All works fine in Chrome and Firefox. In Edge I see little more whitespace while fast scrolling, but still it is ok.

But IE11 freezes on each scroll...its working OK as long as rendered elements are simple, like div with text inside it.

I am rendering empty divs while "isScrolling" and this have positive effect on IE performance, but when scroll ends and real elements are rendering Grid freezes again.
I am using simple Grid, something like Basic Example + windowScroller, and now my Grid is rendering components which returning JSX-object (no heavy logic inside).
CSS for styling Grid elements is external (Not react-side styles).
Elements have no flexbox inside.

I spent several days, but still have problems with IE11 performance.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why IE11 perf would be so bad. Make sure you're running React in production mode as that can definitely have a performance impact?

Comment: Thank You very much, brianvaughn!
As I said, I am new in react. I thought that production build only minimizes a react code. 
Now i have no freezes in IE on scrolls and i am happy. 8)
I will try to play with shouldComponentUpdate() for better performance, but at the moment I am glad to see how my infinite grid works.
Thank You for Your help. This library is amazing.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped. :)